# creating form and storind data in database

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I am creating simple form that accepts input from user and stores that data into database.......but I am  getting the following error..I've tried many solutions..bt not single works!! Plz help me..

Here's My code..club.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clubcs.css">
<title>Friends Club Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="logo.jpg" alt="img" height="200">
</div>
<div class="segment_header" style="width:auto;text-align:Left;">
   <h1 style="font-size:23px;">New Member Registration</h1>
</div>
<div class="text_field">
<p>First Name:<input type="text" name="first"></p>
<p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="last"></p>
<p>Address:<input type="text" name="addr"></p>
<p>City:<input type="text" name="city"></p>
<p>Contact no.:<input type="text" name="contact"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and insert.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"clubinfo");
$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['first']));
$last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['last']));
$addr=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['addr']));
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['city']));
$contact= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,isset($_POST['contact']));
$sql1="INSERT INTO clubdata (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Contact no.)
VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$addr', '$city', '$contact')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "You have successfully registered with us!";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Error is after running the code i.e. after submitting the form..

Comment: You said "but I am getting the following error..I've tried many solutions". You have shown neither.

Comment: Syntax error near ' no. ) VALUES ( `1` , 1` ` , `1` , 1` ` , `1` )' at line 1

Comment: Accept @Fred -ii-'s answer below. He's right.

Comment: you should try using " for you column names like `"Insert into clubdata('Firstname', 'LastName', 'Address', 'City', 'Contact no.')...`

Comment: sorry...i forget that.. bt the error is "Syntax error near ' no. ) VALUES ( `1` , 1` ` , `1` , 1` ` , `1` )' at line 1"

Comment: @Razah I've already tried that...

Comment: Well, take a look at the answer below. The `contact no.` column is definitely the (one..) issue.

Comment: bt where is the @Fred-ii-s answer??

Comment: @PujaJogi Reload the page you are on now.

Comment: now, i've removed contact no column bt still i'm getting same error!

Comment: @PujaJogi Reload my answer with additional information added. One of which is about `isset`

Comment: #Fred -ii- im getting new error as " syntax error, unexpected ';' " after doing correction suggested by you!(there is not any syntax error exist in code as i checked code 3-4 times)

Comment: @PujaJogi You mentioned earlier that you removed the `Contact no.` from your query. Did you remove the comma after `City` --- `(FirstName, LastName, Address, City,` <= ? to read as `(FirstName, LastName, Address, City)` and changing `('$first', '$last', '$addr', '$city', '$contact')` to `('$first', '$last', '$addr', '$city')`

Comment: yes..i did that too!

Comment: @Fred -ii- Finally...error is removed!!Thank you :)

Comment: @PujaJogi Try `('".$first."', '".$last."', '".$addr."', '".$city."')`

Comment: you should use medoo, and make all your database queries simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (unshown in your question) is based on this `Contact no.` being your column.

First, it contains a space and a period. If that is your actual column name, you should consider renaming it to `Contact_no` or use backticks around it.

I.e.:

```
`Contact no.`
```

or removing the period and rename it to (and in your DB):

```
`Contact no`
```

change to

```
(FirstName, LastName, Address, City, `Contact no.`)
```

or remove the period and rename it in DB to `Contact no`

```
(FirstName, LastName, Address, City, `Contact no`)
```

or rename it in your DB to `Contact_no` with an underscore

```
(FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Contact_no)
```

using that type of naming convention is not considered good practice. MySQL will complain about it.

---

For more information on table/column indentifiers, visit the MySQL.com website:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

---

Also, remove all the `isset` from your variables.

```
$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first']);
```

etc.

You may also be injecting characters that MySQL does not agree with, apostrophes, slashes etc.. Using only `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not sufficient. Add `stripslashes()`

I.e.:

```
$first=stripslashes($_POST['first']);
$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first']);
```

etc.

Using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) would be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

No changes in club.php..
few changes in insert.php...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clubcs.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"clubinfo");
$first=stripslashes($_POST['first']);
$first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first']);
$last=stripslashes($_POST['last']);
$last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['last']);
$addr=stripslashes($_POST['addr']);
$addr=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['addr']);
$city=stripslashes($_POST['city']);
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['city']);
$contact=stripslashes($_POST['contact']);
$contact=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['contact']);
$sql1="INSERT INTO clubdata (FirstName, LastName, Address, City,Contact_no)
VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$addr', '$city', '$contact')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "You have successfully registered with us!";
mysqli_close($con);
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you @Fred -ii- once again!!